# Can't understand the reason for an output in Python

Tags: python

I've just started learning Python. I came across following code

> `if 0:`
>
> ```
>   print "And now for something completely different..."
> ```
>
> `else:`
>
> ```
>   print "What's all this, then?"
> ```

I understand that output should be `What's all this, then?` but I can't seem to find a proper explanation for that. Hope someone can make me understand that.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to know *why* someone is writing code like this: I guess it is only for demonstration purpose. There is clearly no need for such a condition.

Comment: Yes it's purely for demo purpose. As I said, I am learning Python. So referring basic documentation yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`0` is `False` in a boolean context. Same applies for empty string, lists, etc.

From the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#booleans):

> In the context of Boolean operations, and also when expressions are used by control flow statements, the following values are interpreted as false: False, None, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets and frozensets). All other values are interpreted as true. (See the [__nonzero__()](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__) special method for a way to change this.)

Answer (score 4):

Zero is interpreted as "false" in python (and many other programming languages)

Answer (score 1):

0 is False. Both boolean and logically and in just about every other case.

What are you confused about?

Answer (score 1):

Numeric zero is always interpreted as false in Python:

http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#booleans

Answer (score 1):

And almost anything that isn't 0 is True when used in a test. Any number (including negatives) is treated as True, but 'None' is False. Non-empty character strings are True, empty ones are False.

Check out boolean or logical functions of Python in the docs. Also, forget everything you ever learnt in basic math(s) at school, because....

```
>>> 1 and 1
1

>>> 2 and 2
2
```

Honestly, that makes sense...

Answer (score 1):

As stated elsewhere, unlike some languages (but like some others), Python will interpret 0 as false, thus the else is activated instead of the then.  To make the then section run, you'd have to do something like `if 1:` (or another non-zero value) instead.  Please don't code like this in real life.  For more, please see the Python docs on [if](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements) (and [another](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#if)) and [booleans](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#booleans).